# How to convert multiple duplicate columns as single row with appreciated values

Tags: sql-server-2016

how to convert multiple duplicate columns as single row with appreciated values
see the image my actually table and expected result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using `PIVOT` to achieve your desired results.

```
--Demo setup
Declare @Table table (FormId int, FieldName varchar(10), [value] varchar(10)) 
insert into @Table(FormId, FieldName, [value]) values
(123,'FirstName','aaaaa'),
(123,'LastName','bbbb'),
(123,'Email','kk@g.com'),
(124,'FirstName','cccc'),
(124,'LastName','dddd'),
(124,'Email','ll@g.com'),
(125,'FirstName','eeee'),
(125,'LastName','ffff'),
(125,'Email','abc@.com')

--The solution
SELECT FormId
    ,FirstName
    ,LastName
    ,Email
FROM (
    SELECT Formid
        ,FieldName
        ,[Value]
    FROM @Table
    ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT(MIN([Value]) --Needs to be an aggregate function
        FOR [FieldName] IN (
            FirstName
            ,LastName
            ,Email
            )) AS PivotOutput
```

---

```
| FormId | FirstName | LastName | Email    |
|--------|-----------|----------|----------|
| 123    | aaaaa     | bbbb     | kk@g.com |
| 124    | cccc      | dddd     | ll@g.com |
| 125    | eeee      | ffff     | abc@.com |
```

You can find more examples by doing an internet search for 'pivot key value pairs'

Comment: thankyou scott,  is it possible in dynamic way ?mean procedures or triggers

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t0 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT formid
             FROM table ) 
SELECT t0.formid, t1.value FirstName, t2.value LastName, t3.value Email
FROM t0
LEFT JOIN table t1 ON t0.formid = t1.formid AND t1.fieldname = 'FirstName'
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t0.formid = t2.formid AND t1.fieldname = 'LastName'
LEFT JOIN table t3 ON t0.formid = t3.formid AND t1.fieldname = 'Email'
```

`(formid, fieldname)` in source table MUST be defined as unique.

Comment: thankyou akina,fieldname's different depending on formid's is it possible in dynamically ?

Comment: No problems, perform this using prepared statement execution. Collect fieldnames array, build query text in a variable, and execute.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic generation of the field list (based on [Scott Hodgin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/60085/scott-hodgin)'s [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244642/150107)):

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000);

WITH fields AS ( SELECT STUFF( ( SELECT ',' + fieldname
                                 FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT test.fieldname
                                        FROM test ) tmp FOR XML PATH('') 
                               ), 1, 1,'' 
                             ) list )
SELECT @sql = 
      'SELECT FormId,' 
      + fields.list 
      + ' FROM (SELECT Formid,FieldName,[Value] ' 
      + 'FROM test) AS SourceTable ' 
      + 'PIVOT(MIN([Value]) ' 
      + 'FOR [FieldName] IN (' 
      + fields.list 
      + ')) AS PivotOutput;'
FROM fields;

EXEC (@sql);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1f0e5566bfa8eb130c14a331b0913567).

If you need the same, but for one (or a list of) selected FormId(s), then add according WHERE into CTE and SourceTable.